# Can you use a 6-7-8 speed masterlink on a single speed chain

Tags: master-link

So it's really simple, I wanna confirm if I can use a 6-7-8 speed masterlink(https://www.amazon.in/Phenovo-1Pair-Bicycle-Chain-Connector/dp/B07BGZVF6C/ref=dp_fod_1?pd_rd_i=B07BGZVF6C&psc=1) on a single speed chain, it's a single speed road bike so it doesnot require any chain tensioner.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6):

6-7-8 speed master links can only be used with 6-7-8 speed chains. You cannot use them with single speed chains. 6-7-8 speed chains are 3/32" but single speed chains are 1/8". You may however find master links that are intended for single speed systems. [Examples of single speed master links](https://www.kmcchain.com/en/series/chain-connector-single-speed).

However, if your sprocket and chainring are 3/32" sprockets, then it's possible to use a 3/32" multi-speed chain (with a compatible master link) on them even though you only have a single speed.

A 3/32" chain won't work with 1/8" sprockets.